# Error with array formula in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

```
 A      B    C   D  
east    1   56
west    5   98
east    1   78
west    5   99
south   3   23
east    2   45
south   3   67
```

I want to get the maximum value of same combination of A+B concatenated. Ex- for east1, I should get 78 in column D. For this I am using VBA, but the code doesn't seem to work. I am using array formula for it.

My code is:

```
.Range("D2:D" & OutputLastRow).FormulaArray = "=MAX(("$A$2:$A$" & OutputLastRow=A2)*("$B$2:$B$" & OutputLastRow=B2)*("$C$2:$C$" & OutputLastRow))"
```

The code is running without any bug but the result comes out to be wrong because the cell A2 as well as B2 is not getting updated as the formula moves down from D2. A2 remains as A2 and B2 as B2. I have tried it using loop but that also doesn't work.

Comment: That line can't run without a bug - it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Consider creating a Pivot Table.  It might result in a neater and more readable report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `.FormulaArray` on a multi-cell range, it's not like putting an array formula in the first cell and auto-filling. You should rather do it explicitly, in two steps. Your code, after some corrections, should be like this:

```
' 1- Enter the array formula in top cell
Range("D2").FormulaArray = _
  "=MAX(($A$2:$A$" & OutputLastRow & "=A2)*($B$2:$B$" & OutputLastRow & _
  "=B2)*($C$2:$C$" & OutputLastRow & "))"

' 2- Then autofill down the column
Range("D2:D" & OutputLastRow).FillDown
```

Alternatively, you could use the `AGGREGATE` function to make a "normal" formula which is exactly equivalent to yours:

```
Range("D2:D" & OutputLastRow).Formula = _
  "=Aggregate(14, 6, ($A$2:$A$" & OutputLastRow & "=A2)*($B$2:$B$" & OutputLastRow & _
  "=B2)*($C$2:$C$" & OutputLastRow & "), 1)"
```

Comment: @AndreTerra `Aggregate` was introduced with Excel 2010. It's **really** powerful and cool. Nevertheless it took a while before I started using it and I often meet Excel skillful users who didn't add it to their arsenal yet.

Comment: @A.S.H..Thanks..The second one with aggregate function worked for me but the array one is still having the same issue of non-updating the cells A2 and B2. I still can't figure out why is it happening...

Comment: @ShashankChandra it could be due to some errors or `#NA`s in the range. The `AGGREGATE` function with option `6` permits to ignore those errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA for this. In `D1` enter the following array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter) and drag it down

`=MAX(IF(A1&B1=$A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7,$C$1:$C$7))`

Your output should look like this:

[image]

The formula works because MAX and MIN ignore the FALSE values for `A1&B1` = `$A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7` and operate only on the remaining results. The array formula makes it so that the `A1&B1` gets compared to the "current row" value for `$A$1:$A$7&$B$1:$B$7`. I guess you could lock columns for `$A1&$B1` like that but in your example it wasn't necessary.